# Importing Data from excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently I am trying to import excel file using asp.net compiled software.

But it generates following error.

> The 'Microsoft.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine'.

what is the solution of this problem?

Comment: You need to install the driver. [Here is the download link for the driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please go through this link. this might be very useful for you.
the Error is you need to install access database engine in your system

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

access database engine download link:http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

if it doesn't works, try installing
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Answer (score 0):

Save excel file as 97-2003 excel workbook and then try connecting that excel.